# Checkbox onchange throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dojo

I'm placing a checkbox inside of my chartbox div. The checkbox is displayed well, but now I want to do some actions after checkbox changed.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" onchange="calc();" checkeddata-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox">
```

```js
function calc() {
    alert("123");
}
```

After I click on the checkbox this error appears:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calc is not defined

So I tested this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" onchange="alert("123");" checkeddata-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox"/>
```

With this code the following error occurs:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Chartbox:

```
new window.EvmClasses.chartBox(_domnodeId, _portletId, {
    "htmlContent": '<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" onchange="calc();" checkeddata-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox">' +  " Minuten bis zur automatischen Aktualisierung",
    "left" : 100,
    "top" : 0,
    "width" : 410,
    "z-index" : 9,
    "height" : 25,
    "bgColorFrom" : "#ffffff",
    "bgColorTo" : "#ffffff",
    "color" : "#000000"
});
```

Comment: Could you add more details/code, please?

Comment: The problem with the first example is because the definition of `calc` is out of scope and in the second HTML sample you have mis-matched quotes on the `onchange` attribute

Comment: you should define the function before using it. where did you defined calc?'

Comment: the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` is resolved if you wirte `onchange="alert('hi')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the `calc` function in the window scope:

```
window.calc = function () {
   alert('123')
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/t1fo8s50/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of double quotes into alert

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" onchange="alert("123");" checkeddata-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox"/>
```

Replace it with single quotes as shown below.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" onchange="alert('123');" checkeddata-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox"/>
```